# Powershell copy-item hangs with large file to network location

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that copies a large (80+ gig) set of files to a network location. Everything worked fine when copying to a location drive but now copying to the backup location on the network the file transfer seems to just hang.  It appears as though the transfer is actually done since the file is the correct size on the destination and there is no network usage when looking at PerfMon so it seems like it is just waiting or confirming something.  Has anyone else seen an issue like this or is there a way to flag the copy operation as "do not validate"?

Comment: Sorry, not a programming question, voting to move to http://serverfault.com/ OR you can 'flag' it and ask for a moderator to move i. (I didn't downvote your question). Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

Powershell is awesome but sometimes calling external programs can provide a more robust solution; I always call Robocopy from Powershell when transferring large files over a network and would recommend you use this approach.

Comment: So you do not share this experience [Robocopy vs Powershell Copy-Item Command](http://itexperiences.blogspot.fr/2010/05/robocopy-vs-powershell-copy-item.html#!/2010/05/robocopy-vs-powershell-copy-item.html)

Comment: Yes, I've seen Robocopy struggle but it's much better since it started supporting SMB2.1 and multi-threading... [metrics](http://www.demartek.com/Demartek_Presenting_RMWTUG_March_2011-03.html) and despite the overhead /Z can be a lifesaver (restartable mode - copy survives a network interruption).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your problem appends because of network troubles or SMB troubles. You don't give any details about the operating systems of the 'from' and 'to' machines, and it can have an impact too.

This is just a suggestion : Have you try to use `Copy-Item` on a remote file system mounted with PowerShell like in the example here-under

```
New-PSDrive -Name Y -PSProvider filesystem -Root \\ServerName\Share
Copy-Item BigFile Y:\BigFileCopy
```

Comment: From and to are both Windows Server 2008 R2